# Contructor de métodos en Java

Tags: java

Antes de nada no quiero que se haga el ejercicio que voy a exponer, simplemente quiero ejemplos para poder entenderlo, soy novato en java y este es el ejercicio que nos han expuesto. Entiendo más o menos lo que se debe hacer, pero no el como. En la unidad explica muy mal como debe de ser y se hace confuso. Ahora mismo estoy en el ejercicio 2.1

Ejercicio 1

Crea un proyecto en NetBeans llamado ElectionDay, con un paquete con el mismo nombre y una clase Partido que se define a continuación:

La clase ‘Partido’ debe tener los atributos: partido, candidato y votos.

```
String partido;   

String candidato;

int votos;

//Añade los métodos set y get, por ejemplo para candidato:

String getCandidato(){
     return candidato;
 }

 void setCandidato(String candidato){
      this.candidato=candidato;
 }
```

2. Crea los siguientes métodos:

2.1.   Crea un método constructor sin argumentos que permita declarar objetos de tipo Partido inicializados con el partido “Democratico”, el candidato tendrá la cadena ”Pendiente de primarias” y los votos serán 0.

2.2.   Método mostrarPartido() que muestra por pantalla los atributos de partido.

2.3.   Un método llamado votar que recibirá como parámetro un número de votos que se sumarán al número de votos del partido.

2.4.   Un método llamado corruptoEncontrado que incrementa el número de votos   en un 5% (realiza un redondeo al alza).

2.5.   Crea el constructor con parámetros.

3. Crea una clase ElectionDay con un método main en la que se instancie un objeto de la clase Partido, que llamaremos partidoA, utilizando el constructor sin argumentos creado anteriormente y se muestre por pantalla el contenido de sus atributos. Modifica el valor del partido, utilizando el método setPartido, a “A”, y modifica el candidato con setCandidato, a “tu nombre” y vuelve a mostrar por pantalla los atributos del Partido.

3.1.   A continuación crea un objeto, partidoB, de la clase Partido  en la clase ElectionDay utilizando el constructor con parámetros y asignando a los parámetros  los valores: "B", "el nombre que quieras", 0, para posteriormente mostrar el contenido de sus atributos por pantalla.

3.2.   A continuación crea un objeto, partidoC, de tipo Partido que inicialice los atributos a los valores que introduzca el usuario por teclado utilizando el constructor con parámetos. Muestra el contenido de los atributos de partidoC por pantalla.

3.3.   Llamaremos a los métodos votar de todos los objetos Partido, con los siguientes números de votos: partidoA 100, partidoB 60, partidoC 30;

3.4.   Según las últimas noticias se encuentran casos de corrupción en partidoA y partidoB, llama a sus métodos corruptoEncontrado y muestra su contenido.

3.5.   Calcularemos los escaños de cada partido (y lo mostraremos por pantalla) utilizando la Cuota Hagenbach-Bischoff, donde el número de votos necesarios para obtener un escaño es :

```
       total de votos__

                       total escaños+1
```

El total de escaños es 10 y el total de votos se obtiene de la suma del atributo votos de los tres objetos.

Comment: Hola @RaúlGarcia , no considero que esa sea la forma correcta de hablarle a un nuevo compañero de la programación Java, con esa actitud este foro no existiría, considera cambiar tu comentario a uno mas "constructivo" por favor. Además el usuario, ha realizado mas preguntas, que han sido bien recibidas por la comunidad en otros lenguajes. Todo el mundo tiene que empezar alguna vez, y no está mal pedir ayuda. Un problema muy concreto, con un ejemplo facil de revisar. Considero que es una pregunta muy apta.

Answer (score 2):

Los constructores en Java nos permiten varias cosas, entre ellas darles valores por defecto a una clase cuando las inicializamos.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso con la clase partido.

**EDITADO**  Gracias a [JDev](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83676/jdev) por la observación

```
public Class Partido (){
    String partido;   
    String candidato;
    int votos;

    public Partido(){
        partido = "Democrata";
        candidato = "Pendiente de elecciones";
        votos = 0;
    }
    //Añade los métodos set y get, por ejemplo para candidato:

    String getCandidato(){
         return candidato;
    }
    void setCandidato(String candidato){
          this.candidato=candidato;
    }
}



Partido partido = new Partido();
```

Ya que el constructor, por defecto le pondrá **siempre** los valores dados en el constructor.

Comment: Ojo, que esta pidiendo constructor sin argumentos

Comment: @JDev bien visto, modifico mi respuesta entonces. Al haber leído lo de los parametros que tendría que tener he dado por hecho que los tendría que pasar en la llamada

Comment: Muchas gracias chicos, visto esto Partido partido = new Partido(); es lo que estaba intentado declarar, según ponía en el temario, pero.....no era así. Haber si puedo acabarlo.

Comment: Como sería Crear el método mostrarPartido();

Comment: @IvanInceraMundogamer te refieres al `getPartido();` ?

Comment: En el punto 2.2 indica Método mostrarPartido() que muestra por pantalla los atributos de partido. No se muy bien como plantearlo. Estoy muy perdido....

Comment: @IvanInceraMundogamer como veo que estás bastante perdido con java en general y me he leído el resto de los puntos, te parece si organizamos una llamada en skype y te echo un cable? Mas que nada porque prefiero explicarte como hacer el ejercicio que directamente ir haciéndote todos los puntos del ejercicio